# Why can't I access property in services from component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this service:

```
export class SummarizeService {
   
  private _myprop: string;
  public get myprop(): string {
    return this._myprop;
  }
  public set myprop(value: string) {
    this._ddd = value;
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

I inject it to the component:

```
export class HomePlanCardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private summarizeService: SummarizeService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}      
  
  add(){    
     this.summarizeService.ddd("test");
  }
}
```

On this row under myprop:

```
this.summarizeService.myprop("test");
```

I get this error:

> This expression is not callable.
> Type 'String' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Any idea why I can't access the set property of the service in the component?

Answer (score 0):

Since `myprop` is a getter/setter and not a function, you can't call it. Here's how to set the value:

```
this.summarizeService.myprop="test";
```